# Mod Redirect Oddity

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a redirect working mostly but with one exception when a url is run without a forward slash the redirect shows in the address bar, this is not the behavior I'm expecting.  Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*)  redirector.php?subdomain=%1 [QSA,L]
```

now if there is a subdomain on my domain I want that request to go to the redirector.php file and this works in all cases unless I have a folder without a backslash.  I've also tried putting in an optional forward slash at the end of the condition, still no go.  So what happens when there is no forward slash at the end of a folder is that the request goes from

```
http://test2.domain.com/test
```

to

```
http://test2.domain.com/test/?subdomain=test2
```

cannot figure out how to get it to stop as

```
http://test2.domain.com/test/
```

will work.

Answer (score 0):

ah figured it out you can easily check to see if the request doesn't have a file name and if so redirect with a forward-slash!  So now I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*)  redirector.php?subdomain=%1 [QSA,L]
```